# Parameter of generic type extends a class

Tags: typescript, ngrx

There is a class of type `Action` . 
I need to declare a function such that it takes a parameter of a class which extends Action along with additional parameter . For ex:

```
class Abc extends Action {
    payload: any;
}
```

My actual function :

```
function xyz(action: Abc){
    // ...
}
```

But `action: Abc` should be generic something like

```
action: {payload: string} extends Action
```

Scenario (Optional): 
I am struggling with this as ngrx 4 removed payload from Action but my older code expects it to have payload .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost right. Change it to this

```
private xyz = (action: { payload: string } & Action) => {
}
```

Look here for [Typescript Intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)